# How to pass an instance of a subclass to a superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism

I have like a 3 layer inheretance like Superclass1->subclass1->subclass2. I am using hiberate to create this project and the basic idea is, when persisting a data, I want to execute that on the Superclass1 level. So that anyone extending that superclass will be able to persist any data in there respective table just by calling a method.

The main purpose why I did this is to have a sort of event timing where I can override it whenever I like. It's something like this:

This to make all my model execute the functions I need in a higher level.

```
public class interfaces SuperModifier() {

    Boolean save();

    void beforeSave();

    void afterSave();

    void delete();
}
```

This implements the interfaces class. To execute the save() and other iplemetned function. I'm already good with the session part, and I was able to save the data already. I am just enhancing my code for scalability and for it to be reusable.

```
public class Superclass implements SuperModifier{

    Object newInstance;

    public Boolean save() {

        try {

            Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(newInstance); <-- this part rigth here
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
           transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

This is where I define all the columns with annotation.

```
public class Subclass1 extends Superclass() {

    // because this is hibernate
    // I placed all my defintion of columns here
}
```

and this class is where my setters and getters are located. and other functions I may need for this model.

```
public class Subclass2 extends Subclass1() {


    // I placed all functions here like setters and getters
}
```

And of course the main function.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Subclass2 sub = new Subclass2();
    sub.setName("New Instance");
    sub.save(); // <--called because of the superclass
}
```

You see the line **session.save(newInstance);** that newInstance variable is what I am having trouble with. how do I pass the instance created in the main method to be able to save in its superclass?

I was thinking passing it through the constructor but its impossible because it not yet created. I was also thinking making a setter in the superclass to set the newInstance in, but when do I execute the set?

I was also thinking **sub.save(sub);**, but it just looks wrong. :)

Any ideas? I hope you get my point. Is my structure wrong? if it is, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Mix your Entities with Persisting logic is not really a good idea, because:

- you can't control the transaction boundaries properly (your save method assumes there's no transaction in progress, so it attempts to create one)
- the Entity class has dependencies on the Hibernate API classes, so if you aim to export them to the UI layer, the UI would require a dependency on Hibernate too.

Try separating the persisting logic in a Service layer instead.

As for your question, the subclass entity is also a superclass entity too, so you only need to save it once.

Comment: I'm going to focus first on this then enhance it more. Anyway, the save() function exist and is called because of the superclass(Superclass). On the created instance sub.save() it is not yet really saved because it will still go inside the save() function of the superclass because it is not overridden. Now, once it goes inside, the problem is the session.save(newInstance) where I do not know how to pass the "newInstance" variable which it is the created instance in the main funciton, "sub".

Comment: The `Superclass` newInstance is an instance attribute and your `save` method should probably save the `this` reference anyway.

Comment: no because in the first place newInstance variable has not yet been either declared a value or instantiated at any point. It may have been declared as a global variable on the Superclass but that's it, there was no value yet. Or are you saying that I should just do something like session.save(this); instead?

Comment: Anything else than `session.save(this);` sounds worse.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what are you trying to say to resolve my question. Can you elaborate and make things more clear? Thank you.

Comment: Your structure is indeed wrong and I already gave you the solution: "Try separating the persisting logic in a Service layer instead"